# Is it good to save a large file in ram for a while?

Tags: heroku, youtube, server, ram

So I have a bunch of videos hosted on dropbox, and I have to build a web app for my client that get those videos from dropbox and upload them to youtube, I've came with the following solutions :

**First** : Once my app got a dropbox link, it use the API to download it on the server filesystem, after that it will use the youtube API to upload it

**Problem with this** : The only problem I will face here, is that I'm hosting the app on heroku, and heroku has an ephemral filesystem which is not that good for storing files, also videos could be large exceeding 100mb and that's not allowed by heroku .

**Solution** : I can keep the file on the ram, which is around 512 mb for a free dyno and agter uploading to youtube I delete it !

So my basic question here is whether it'd be good to save a large file in RAM for some time ?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a good idea. What if you have a few people downloading videos in parallel?

It looks like you need a [worker dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) for your app, that would do the actual downloading and free up your web dyno.

You need to keep all your dynos stateless and [disposable](http://12factor.net/disposability), and so should use some kind of [backing service](http://12factor.net/backing-services) such as [Heroku Redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis) for storing your videos.

This [blog post](https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal/case-studies/case-study-how-hulu-scaled-serving-4-billion-videos-using-redis) might give you some ideas.